# Sass advanced nesting: applying a pseudo selector several levels up

Tags: css, sass

I need some help with advanced sass nesting. Assume I have checkbox styles that look like this.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  + label {
    // ...

    &::before {
      // ...
    }
  }

  &:hover + label::before {
    // hover styles
  }

  &:focus + label::before {
    // focus styles
  }
}
```

But I want to nest the hover and focus styles under `+ label` and `&::before` above. I think this would be cleaner to read and maintain. Is there a way to do this in sass? Am I approaching this wrong? How is this type of thing typically handled?

In the sass documentation they have a [sort of similar example](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector#advanced-nesting) but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how I could apply that type of thing here.

Comment: Honestly, I like your current approach. I don't think Sass' selector functions will make your code more readable/maintainable. Moreover, the selector functions are pretty obscure, so they're likely to confuse other people who look at the code in the future.

Comment: I agree with @mfluehr. I think you are overthinking this. I could look at your code and know exactly what CSS will output.

Comment: I just feel like it's not very DRY. I feel like I want to put all of the styles for the `::before` element in one block, rather than spreading it out. I'm worried it get's out of hand in more complicated examples. But I can accept that I'm overthinking things. Thanks for your responses!